# Any way to update VARBINARY value on certain position?

Tags: mysql

for example, if i have string `'012345678'`, and i need to update position number 4 into another byte/character `'x'` for example:

```
INSERT INTO foo(pk,pos) VALUES('abcdefghi',5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  pk = CONCAT(
     SUBSTRING(pk,1,VALUES(pos)-1),
     SUBSTRING(VALUES(pk),VALUES(pos),1),
     SUBSTRING(pk,VALUES(pos)+1)
  );

-- simpler example:
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('abcdefghi',1,5-1),SUBSTRING('123456789',5,1),SUBSTRING('abcdefghi',5+1));
-- abcd5fghi
```

how to do this in `VARBINARY` data type?

Comment: `HEX/replace/UNHEX` may solve, for example.

Comment: How does that fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) function:

```
INSERT(String, StartingPosition, CharsToDelete, 'StringToInsert')
```

So if you wanted to replace one character at position 4 in the string `abcdefghi`, the expression would go like this:

```
INSERT('abcdefghi', 4, 1, 'x')
```

See for yourself in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fe6dce5a075bc38ef4524effaab19aab).

The expression would only *return* a modified string. Use it in an assignment to actually write the result, where necessary.